# Facebook Like button functionality without IFRAME or Javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add Facebook "Like" functionality to a native mobile app i.e. Not one running in a browser.

I can retrieve the Likes for an item from the Graph API but I cannot see how to POST a "Like" operation using that API. How do I do that?

Am I going to have do have a browser control hidden with the app that uses an IFRAME?

TIA

Pat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Facebook graph api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), you can like any object that has a /likes connection by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes. This would work for friends posts, comments, etc.

But I don't believe there is an API to "like" a page (become a fan) and probably won't be because it would be abused by spammers.  You will need to embed an web view control in your application for this.